# Video with masked objects that need shadows

Tags: tracking

I have created simple shadow objects for stills in the past where I masked out the environment around product photographs and the shadows matched fine, using the blam add on. Now I am trying to create shadow objects for a video, but the shadow objects don't match the masked objects for more than a couple frames. The solve error for the tracking is 0.14. Shouldn't objects in the virtual environment match the video almost perfectly?

Comment: Yes but maybe they didn't match to well with Blam either but you couldn't tell because there was a sample size of 1 image to assess. If your camera had stabilization during the shoot the center of the image will drift and give you a bad solve over time. Also see other answers here for achieving a better track.

Comment: Read: [How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking)

Answer (score 0):

They *should*, but there are so many factors to take into consideration, it's not a good idea to rely on only one shot. If you can pinpoint where the camera is changing, make a different scene or use a different camera for those clips and lace them together in compositing, or simply do your best with moving the shadow plane around to match where it *should* be going, and see if it's good enough for your purposes.